# Render error with Cycles engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am doing a render with Cycles in Blender 3.6, and some frames look like a glitch with a big square of blue and black color. If someone can help me I would be very grateful. I share two pictures, one with the scene, and the other with the render of the scene.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. we can't really help you with so little details, we can only guess. Probably need the blend file for this. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hi Harry thank you for help me I cant send you the file beacuse is to heavy, can I send you with a wetransfer link ?

Comment: You can easily isolate the problem by removing assets one by one and testing each render until the black goes away. Then just before it goes away you can clean the file with *File > Clean Up*. Than *Save As* another file. This way it will be smaller.

Comment: Okey I gona try to remove one by one thank you for help :)

Comment: I do that and I find the error thank you I appreciate your help so much

Comment: @AlvaroR. If you did find the error, then please answer the self answer the question. So that if someone else having the same issue visits the site, thne that person will be able to refer to the answer provided by you